# Is blockingget safe to use in background thread

Tags: android, rx-java

I am basically trying to map a List to a string in rxjava in background thread.For that purpose i am using blocking get.Is it safe or there is any better way of doing it.Does i loose my asynchronous here using blockingGet?

```
 private Observable<Movie> getGenreObservable(Movie movie){
    return HttpCall.getRequest().getMovieGenres("").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new Function<MovieGenreList, List<Genre>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Genre> apply(MovieGenreList movieGenreList) throws Throwable {
                    return movieGenreList.getGenres();
                }
            }).flatMap(new Function<List<Genre>, ObservableSource<List<Genre>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<List<Genre>> apply(List<Genre> genres) throws Throwable {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(genres).filter(new Predicate<Genre>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean test(Genre genre) throws Throwable {
                            for(Integer id:movie.getGenreIds()){
                                if(id == genre.getId()) return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).toList().toObservable();
                }
            }).map(new Function<List<Genre>, List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public List<String> apply(List<Genre> genres) throws Throwable {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(genres).map(new Function<Genre, String>() {
                        public String apply(Genre genre) {
                            return genre.getName();
                        }
                    }).toList().blockingGet();
                }
            }).map(new Function<List<String>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(List<String> strings) throws Throwable {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(strings).reduce(new BiFunction<String, String, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String apply(String s, String s2) throws Throwable {
                            return s+", "+s2;
                        }
                    }).blockingGet();
                }
            }).map(new Function<String, Movie>() {
                @Override
                public Movie apply(String s) throws Throwable {
                    movie.setGenreNames(s);
                    return movie;
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use `.flatMap` instead of `.map`, so that the need for `blockingGet` is removed?

```java
 private Observable<Movie> getGenreObservable(Movie movie){
    return HttpCall.getRequest().getMovieGenres("").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new Function<MovieGenreList, List<Genre>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Genre> apply(MovieGenreList movieGenreList) throws Throwable {
                    return movieGenreList.getGenres();
                }
            }).flatMap(new Function<List<Genre>, ObservableSource<List<Genre>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<List<Genre>> apply(List<Genre> genres) throws Throwable {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(genres).filter(new Predicate<Genre>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean test(Genre genre) throws Throwable {
                            for(Integer id:movie.getGenreIds()){
                                if(id == genre.getId()) return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).toList().toObservable();
                }
            }).flatMap(new Function<List<Genre>, Observable<List<String>>>() {
                @Override
                public List<String> apply(List<Genre> genres) throws Throwable {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(genres).map(new Function<Genre, String>() {
                        public String apply(Genre genre) {
                            return genre.getName();
                        }
                    }).toList();
                }
            }).flatMap(new Function<List<String>, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(List<String> strings) throws Throwable {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(strings).reduce(new BiFunction<String, String, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String apply(String s, String s2) throws Throwable {
                            return s+", "+s2;
                        }
                    })
                }
            }).map(new Function<String, Movie>() {
                @Override
                public Movie apply(String s) throws Throwable {
                    movie.setGenreNames(s);
                    return movie;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Yes,That would solve the problem but i just want to know should we use blockingget in production code or not

Comment: @TARAMISHRA It really depends on your use-case. Generally I would say you should avoid it, unless you've got a good reason to use it and know it won't be blocking a thread it that shouldn't be blocked.